# How to Combine IF statements in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

The following formulas work individually but when I combine them I get a VALUE error, please help!

=IF(AND(LEFT(D7,14)="Cost Avoidance")*AND(AI7>=100000),"Yes, provide validation form in column AK","No")

=IF(AND(LEFT(D7,14)="Cost Reduction")*AND(AI7>=50000),"Yes, provide validation form in column AK","No")

Combined (**doesn't work**): =IF(LEFT(D7,14)="Cost Avoidance"*AND(AI7>=100000),"Yes, provide validation form in column AK",IF(LEFT(D7,14)="Cost Reduction"*AND(AI7>=50000),"Yes, provide validation form in column AK","No"))

Comment: Excel doesn't work as you would write it in an English sentence.  Functions need to follow a prescribed syntax (which makes sense once you check the documentation).  When you write formulas, pay attention to the context prompts that are provided as guides, or use the function wizard (script `f` icon), which will open a dialog window to guide your entry.  When you use a function for the first time, and your guess at the syntax produces an error, there's also tons of other help available (Excel help, Google, etc.).  Don't start with the assumption that it should work the way you guessed.

Comment: Please help me combine the two formulas shown above. I can't figure this out :(

Comment: @fixer1234 that's not very helpful. Care to help or no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=IF(AND(LEFT(D7,14)="Cost Avoidance",AI7>=100000),"Yes, provide validation form in column AK",IF(AND(LEFT(D7,14)="Cost Reduction",AI7>=50000),"Yes, provide validation form in column AK","No"))

Solved it on my own

Comment: Kudos for figuring it out.  I saw your comment and was working on an answer while you were documenting your own solution.  What you figured out will work.  You can actually simplify it a little by using OR instead of nested IFs (see how I did it in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

`IF( AND( expression; expression2; expression3; ...) ; "All true"; "All false")`

To get "help" on any function, e.g. for AND:
In Excel,
- press F1,
- then find the /Search\ -tab and
- enter `AND` in the search field,
- press ENTER,
- find `AND (function)` and click on it...
- read the text.

*From memory, allow for small differences to the above.*
*NOTE: `;` or `,` between values - depends on your locale settings.*

Comment: Could you put it together for me using the formulas I gave you? Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Hannu's answer covers it but if you're new to Excel, the syntax might seem odd.  I'll expand the explanation.

The AND syntax is:

```
AND(condition1,condition2,...)
```

The various conditions that must all be true are a list inside AND, separated by commas.  AND returns a value of TRUE if all the conditions in the list are true, and FALSE otherwise.  So your two AND expressions would look like:

```
AND( LEFT(D7,14)="Cost Avoidance"), AI7>=100000 )
AND( LEFT(D7,14)="Cost Reduction"), AI7>=50000 )
```

Each AND expression returns a value of TRUE or FALSE, so the entire expression can be used in places where you want to make a decision based on some condition or conditions being TRUE or FALSE.

The IF function tests whether something is TRUE or FALSE, and returns a result for each case:

```
IF( condition, result_if_TRUE, result_if_FALSE)
```

That condition can be your entire AND expression.

From your description, you have two different AND expressions, and you want the same set of TRUE/FALSE results if either is true.  You can use OR for that.  Like AND, the syntax is:

```
OR(condition1, condition2,...)
```

You give it a list of conditions.  OR returns TRUE if any one or more of the conditions in the list is TRUE, and FALSE if none are true.

Those conditions can be anything that returns a TRUE/FALSE result, including your AND expressions.  So each AND expression can be a condition in the OR list.  You get:

```
OR( AND(LEFT(D7,14)="Cost Avoidance"),AI7>=100000), AND(LEFT(D7,14)="Cost Reduction"),AI7>=50000) )
```

This entire OR expression produces a TRUE/FALSE result, so it can be used as the condition in your IF test:

```
IF( OR(AND(LEFT(D7,14)="Cost Avoidance"),AI7>=100000),AND(LEFT(D7,14)="Cost Reduction"),AI7>=50000)), "Yes, provide validation form in column AK", "No" )
```

All of this depends, of course, on your question accurately describing what you want to do.  Also, be aware that the list and argument separators can vary by locale.  In some locales, a semi-colon is used rather than a comma.  If you use the function wizard to help build your formula, it will insert the correct separator character.